# Backbone JS - How to create View based on PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have some PHP code which I want to implement into my Backbone App. I use the PHP Framework Codeigniter as Backend and the Restful API to make these two Frameworks talk to each other.

So my php code looks like this:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class social_feeds extends CI_Controller 
{

function instagram($artist_id , $user_name = '')
{
    if($user_name=='')
    {
        exit;//redirect('');
    }

    $user_search_data = $this->instagram_api->userSearch($user_name);

    if(isset($user_search_data->data)) 
    {
        if(count($user_search_data->data) != 0) 
        {
            $array_users = $user_search_data->data;
            foreach($array_users as $users)
            {
                if($users->username== $user_name )
                {
                    $user_recent_data = $this->instagram_api->getUserRecent($users->id);
                    //print_r($user_recent_data);
                    if(!isset($user_recent_data->meta->error_message))
                    {
                        if(is_array($user_recent_data->data))
                        {
                            $counter = 0;
                            foreach($user_recent_data->data as $feed_data)
                            {
                                //print_r($feed_data);

                                /*$image = array('src' => $feed_data->images->standard_resolution->url);
                                if(count($feed_data->tags) > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach($feed_data->tags as $tag)
                                    {
                                        echo $tag;
                                    } 
                                }*/


                                $array[$counter]['title']           = $feed_data->images->standard_resolution->url;
                                $array[$counter]['description']     = $feed_data->caption->text;
                                $array[$counter]['pubDate']         = $feed_data->caption->created_time;
                                $array[$counter]['link']            = $feed_data->link;
                                $array[$counter]['type']            = 'Instagram';
                                ++$counter;
                                if($counter==5)
                                {
                                //  break;
                                }

                                //print_r($array);

                            }
                            $result = json_encode($array);
                            echo $result;
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
}

?>
```

and my Backbone View looks like this so far:

```
define([

'app',
'backbone'

],

function (App, Backbone) {

    // Create a new module.
    var Instagram = App.module();

    // Create view
    Instagram.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'instagram',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    Instagram.InstagramCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return './index.php/api/social_feeds/instagram/' + this.artist_id;
        }
    });

    return Instagram;
});
```

And in my MainView I do the fetch:

```
var instagramCollection = new Instagram.InstagramCollection();
    instagramCollection.artist_id = this.artist_id;
    this.insertView('.artistSocialUpdates', new Instagram.View({collection: instagramCollection}));
    instagramCollection.fetch();
```

And then my HTML template looks like:

```
{{#each this}}
 <p>{{title}}</p>
 <p>{{description}}</p>
 <p>{{pubDate}}</p>
 <p>{{link}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

But apparently this doesnt work...

is there someone who can give me a hint or tell me what I might do or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't mention what templating engine you're using. The template you've posted looks like Handlebars, but your view code doesn't give any indication that you're using Handlebars.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Oh sorry! yes, I'm using HandlebarsJS...

Comment: I also can't see any `render` function. If you haven't defined it that would likely be the problem. Is the browser development console showing an error of some sort?

Comment: @MatthewDaly I render my views in an additional controller which I havent pasted in here... my console is not showing any error, it shows my nothing actually :)